# notifyItemInsertedRange() not working on recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I used recyclerview on my project. I have a problem updating the data. I want to use notifyItemRangeInserted() or notifyItemInserted() method but none of them are working(the arraylist are updated, but the new item is not showing in the recyclerview). It's really confusing because notifyDataSetChanged() is works.

I have tried both notifyItemInserted(index) and notifyItemRangeInserted(startIndex, insertedCount) but none of them works. I also have googled this problem but I didn't find a similar problem.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UrlHouse.MOMENT_EXTENTION,
                response -> {
                    // response
                    Log.e("moment_extention", response);
                    try {
                        JSONArray momentArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        CustomJsonParser jsonParser = new CustomJsonParser(this);
                        for(int i = 0; i < momentArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject c = momentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            momentArrayList.add(jsonParser.parseMomentData(c));
                        }
                        if (momentArray.length() > 0){
                            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                Log.e("item_count", String.valueOf(mAdapter.getItemCount()));
                                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                //mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(10);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(momentArrayList.size() - momentArray.length(), momentArray.length());
                            });
                        }
                        if (momentArray.length()  < 10){
                            stopLoading = true;
                            extentionLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }else{
                            extentionLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                error -> {
                    // error
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("key_owner", userData.getUserId());
                params.put("session_key", userData.getLoginKey());
                params.put("user_id", userData.getUserId());
                params.put("excluded_post", getExcludedPost());
                return params;
            }
        };
        postRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, 0, 1f) );
        queue.add(postRequest);
```

I want the recyclerview item updated the new data. in my case, after updating the adapter it should be 20 item displayed on the screen(10 the original item and 10 is the new item), but instead of displaying 20 item its only displaying 10 item(only the original 10 item)

Comment: I don't see a call to update the data in the mAdapter, something like, mAdapter.setData(MOMENT_LIST) and then call mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(from, count)

Comment: @RahulShukla the mAdapter is defined inside onCreate. I already called mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted inside runOnUiThread()

Comment: Once you get new item list, you need to set this new list to the adapter and then call notify

Comment: @RahulShukla do you see the I log the "item_count"? It shows 20 from the mAdapter.getItemCount(). I mean the adapter has been notified that the arraylist has been updated. but it only display 10 item in the recyclerview

Comment: could you please try 
momentArrayList.add(0, jsonParser.parseMomentData(c));
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, momentArray.length());

Comment: Also didn't work. I think there is no problem with the arraylist since the getItemCount() on the adapter return the new size of arraylist.

Comment: is it possible to share your project?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. What about I share the whole java class(including the activity, adapter, and object class)? @RahulShukla

Comment: That's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using momentArray.length() as endPoint of range and that's why it is not working.

So just replace below line in runOnUiThread(),

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(momentArrayList.size() - momentArray.length(), momentArray.length());
```

To,

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(momentArrayList.size() - momentArray.length() + 1, momentArray.length());
```

Comment: @KevinCiang I have updated few lines in code. Will you please try again with that code?